# ImportError: cannot import name 'Category'

Tags: django

Я знаю, что в интернете много решений этой проблемы, но что-бы я не пробовал получается ошибка -

```
Reverse for 'get_category' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category/(?P<alias>[^/]+)'].
```

template

```
<a href="{% url 'get_category' category.alias %}">
```

views

```
def products(request, alias):
    try:
        product = Items.objects.get(alias=alias)
        title = product.name
    except:
        raise Http404("Объект не найден")

    context = {

    }

    return render(request, 'product/product.html', context)


def get_category(request, alias):
    try:
        category = Category.objects.get(alias=alias)
        products = Items.objects.filter(category=category)
    except:
        raise Http404('Объекты не найден')
    context = {
        'products': products,
        'category': category,
    }
    return render(request, 'popular/popular.html', context)
```

urls

```
url(r'^$', views.popular, name='popular'),
url(r'^products/(?P<alias>[^/]+)', views.products, name='product'),
url(r'^category/(?P<alias>[^/]+)', views.get_category, name='get_category'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по этому

```
with arguments '('',)'
```

у одной из моделей атрибут **alias** пустой. Если предпологается что такое допустимо то нужно это обрабатывать. Необходимов во view **get_category** добавить alias=None

```
def get_category(request, alias=None):
```

а в urls.py

```
url(r'^category/', views.get_category, name='get_category'),
```

Comment: К сожалению та-же ошибка, только теперь когда я ввожу в адресную строку http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/ctg_1 то выдаёт ошибку 404, хотя раньше, если просто ввести в строку alias, работало.